# How can I re-create this histogram-and-curve-combo plot for logistic regression results in ggplot2?

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, logistic-regression

I want to visualize the results of a logistic regression analysis and came across this nifty plot [here](http://www.shizukalab.com/toolkits/plotting-logistic-regression-in-r):

[hope this works http://www.shizukalab.com/toolkits/plotting-logistic-regression-in-r/logistic_1.jpg](http://www.shizukalab.com/toolkits/plotting-logistic-regression-in-r/logistic_1.jpg)

I would like to re-create this plot in ggplot don't know how to approach it. Specifically, how would I add an upside-down histogram to the "top" of the plot?

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

Be warned that trying to do this with two distinct axes is going to be messy, and is probably a bad idea. However, you should be able to replicate that plot with the following approach.

First, some sample data:

```
df <-
  data.frame(
    x = c(rnorm(100, 30,2)
          , rnorm(100, 28, 2))
    , response = factor(rep(c("Y","N"), each = 100))
  )
```

Just to see what we are working with, here is the more traditional plot type:

```
df %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = x, y = as.numeric(response) - 1)) +
  geom_jitter(height = 0.2) +
  stat_smooth(method="glm", family="binomial") +
  ylab("Probability")
```

[image]

Then, we need to construct the bins that we will use to plot. I am cutting the data at the locations I want breaks (here, using `pretty` to automate it), converting to a fraction of the data, then generating x/y ranges to use for making rectangles to mimic the histogram.

```
binned <-
  df %>%
  mutate(bin = cut(x, pretty(x))) %$%
  table(bin, response) %>%
  prop.table() %>%
  as.data.frame() %>%
  separate(bin, c("xmin","xmax"), ",") %>%
  mutate_each(funs(parse_number(.)), xmin, xmax) %>%
  mutate(ymin = ifelse(response == "N"
                       , 0
                       , 1 - Freq)
         , ymax = ifelse(response == "Y"
                         , 1
                         , Freq))
```

Then, pass each data type to a different `geom_*`, and you should get the plot you want:

```
ggplot() +
  geom_rect(
    aes(xmin = xmin, xmax = xmax, ymin = ymin, ymax = ymax)
    , data = binned
  ) +
  stat_smooth(
    mapping = aes(x = x, y = as.numeric(response) - 1)
    , data = df
    , method="glm", family="binomial") +
  ylab("Probability/Portion of data in category")
```

[image]

You would then want to play with axes/labels to suit your needs. Of note, if you want the bars bigger or smaller (depending on your needs), you could accomplish that by changing the specification of `ymin` and `ymax` to include a multiplier (e.g. changing `Freq` to `Freq * 2`) though that will change the interpretation of the height of the bars.